# How to fix Unclosed block SCSS error while runnig gulp build command

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gulp, gulp-sass

I am getting below error while running "gulp build" command to generate build for production server in a project. Please see error below :

```
[Autoprefixer] Error in plugin 'gulp-autoprefixer'
Message:
    vendor.scss:1:1: Unclosed block
Details:
    file: vendor.scss
    line: 1
    column: 1
    source: $icon-font-path: "../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";

/* Do not remove these comments below. It's the markers used by wiredep to inject
   sass dependencies when defined in the bower.json of your dependencies */
// bower:scss
@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";
// endbower
```

I have searched a lot on google but could not find any proper solution.

Please help me out by giving any solution to fix the above issue.
Thanks in advance.